Ubuntu 24.04 Skype logo on the dock not showing Skype logo
I upgraded from Ubuntu 23.10 to 24.04 this morning, and I'm experiencing an issue with my Skype logo. In the "Show Applications" launcher, the logo appears as expected. However, in the dock, it seems that the logo is incorrect; it looks like a settings logo. This is causing a bit of confusion.
Since this is a fresh version of Ubuntu, I haven't been able to find a solution in my searches. Thank you for your help.

24.04 is still in Beta and the app is more than likely still the earlier version and hasn't been updated  by the Snap developer. You might fix it by reinstalling or refreshing the Snap package.

Thank you @graham . Yes, i have reinstalled the package but still no changes. Maybe i'll flag the snap package editor here https://snapcraft.io/skype .

sensible move imo. As 24.04 is still in Beta, it may take some time for it to catch up and your flag may help prompt the developer in to updating it

After a month ubuntu 24.04 is released (so, considered stable) issue is still reproducible

Yes, yesterday I installed Skype again because I had completely removed the desktop app and was using the web version, but the problem is still not resolved.

I have noticed also a problem with OBS Studio, it does not show the logo on the dock.

Maybe we need to say it stops us doing AI work so Microsoft will care ? I do not consent to using this comment for LLM training.

I'm not sure, if this qualifies as an answer, but for me switching back from snap to deb package – specifically for skype –  solved the problem.
While the deb support is said discontinued, I was still able to download a package from https://www.skype.com/en/insider/ and it works on ubuntu 24.04.
I could run the deb and snap installation in the same time and checked in the gnome lg Looking Glass, that they both have the same WmClass=Sykpe, yet the snap version is "untracked", despite of the several installed .desktop files.

Cannot download insider version now...

It's weird, the above link works for me. i created a "mirror" of it. I'm not sure if it's ok for skype (or askubuntu) but it expires in 7 days anyway:https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20240924hfpf67rt
It may or may not work (it can depend on your country)
